# Transformar petición HTTP Java a CURL

Tags: java, windows, http, cmd, curl

Estoy haciendo un desarrollo que implica la invocación de una librería para obtener información de una cámara WiFi. La cámara implementa una librería con tecnología ISAPI la cual es invocada mediante petición HTTP. He logrado realizar las llamadas y recibir la respuesta en un programa hecho en Java.

El código es el siguiente:

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.connectTimeoutMillis();
    MediaType XML = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
    String authString = "user:pass";
    String authStringEnc = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes()));
    String myXML = "<CountingStatisticsDescription>"
            + "<statisticType>exitnum</statisticType>"
            + "<reportType>daily</reportType>"
            + "<timeSpanList>"
            + "<timeSpan>"
            + "<startTime>2019-02-12T00:00:00</startTime>"
            + "<endTime>2019-02-12T23:59:00</endTime>"
            + "</timeSpan>"
            + "</timeSpanList>"
            + "</CountingStatisticsDescription>";
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(XML, myXML);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://ip:port/ISAPI/System/Video/inputs/channels/1/counting/search")
            .get()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();

    Response response = null;
    try {
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String body = null;
    try {
        body = IOUtils.toString(response.body().byteStream(), "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

La idea es que intento convertir esta llamada con Java a una llamada con CURL que se ejecute desde una consola CMD de Windows. Lo cierto es que no sé mucho de CURL pero investigando un poco he adquirido unas nociones básicas.

La traducción de la llamada HTTP la intento hacer de esta manera:

```
curl -X GET ^
  http://ip:port/ISAPI/System/Video/inputs/channels/1/counting/search ^
  -u user:pass ^
  -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' ^
  -d '<CountingStatisticsDescription version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.isapi.org/ver20/XMLSchema">
    <statisticType>enternum</statisticType>
    <reportType>daily</reportType>
    <timeSpanList>
        <timeSpan>
            <startTime>2019-02-01T00:00:00</startTime>
            <endTime>2019-02-01T23:59:00</endTime>
        </timeSpan>
    </timeSpanList>
</CountingStatisticsDescription>'
```

Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto este comando la consola de Windows me imprime el siguiente mensaje: "No se esperaba < en este momento".

Cualquier sugerencia será de ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos tipos de problema en tu comando:

1. Problemas de sintaxis para la shell de windows. En concreto:

   - El carácter para delimitar cadenas ha de ser siempre `"`, y no `'`
   - Esto implica que el trozo XML dará problemas, pues contiene también comillas `"` que habría que escapar.
   - Al final de cada línea debes usar el "escape" `^` incluso para lo que va entre comillas (la parte del XML), o de lo contrario Windows verá que el comando se ha terminado (donde acabe la línea) sin que hayas cerrado comilllas.
   - El trozo XML también hace uso de los caracteres `<` y `>` que son especiales para windows (la redirección de la entrada/salida), por lo que habría que escaparlos también.
2. Problemas de cara al propio comando CURL, pues le estás pasando un parámetro `-d`, que es para adjuntar un cuerpo en la petición, pero en cambio estás usando la petición `GET`, que nunca puede llevar un cuerpo asociado.

Para resolver los múltiples problemas del punto 1, lo más sencillo es meter todo ese XML en un fichero, por ejemlo `cuerpo.xml` y entonces usar la opción `-d @cuerpo.xml` en CURL. Mis intentos de escapar correctamente el XML para que el shell de windows lo aceptara no han tenido éxito.

El segundo punto es más conflictivo, ya que no sé qué querías hacer exactamente. Supongamos que querías hacer POST en vez de GET. En ese caso el siguiente comando sería lo que buscas:

```
curl.exe -X POST ^
  http://ip:port/ISAPI/System/Video/inputs/channels/1/counting/search ^
  -u user:pass ^
  -H "Content-Type: application/xml" ^
  -d @cuerpo.xml
```

Para ver si funciona correctamente, y ya que no tengo acceso a tu URL real, he hecho la petición a la URL `http://postman-echo.com/post` que es un servidor que te devuelve como resultado un JSON que te permite inspeccionar qué ha recibido (cabeceras, cuerpo, etc.) Me sale lo siguiente (he formateado la respuesta del servidor para mejor legibilidad, pues lo devuelve en una sola línea):

```
curl.exe -X POST ^
   http://postman-echo.com/post ^
   -u user:pass ^
   -H "Content-Type: application/xml" ^
   -d @cuerpo.xml
```

```json
{
    "args": {},
    "data": "<CountingStatisticsDescription version=\"2.0\" xmlns=\"http://www.isapi.org/ver20/XMLSchema\">    <statisticType>enternum</statisticType>    <reportType>daily</reportType>    <timeSpanList>        <timeSpan>            <startTime>2019-02-01T00:00:00</startTime>            <endTime>2019-02-01T23:59:00</endTime>        </timeSpan>    </timeSpanList></CountingStatisticsDescription>",
    "files": {},
    "form": {},
    "headers": {
        "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
        "host": "postman-echo.com",
        "content-length": "377",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "authorization": "Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz",
        "content-type": "application/xml",
        "user-agent": "curl/7.64.0",
        "x-forwarded-port": "80"
    },
    "json": null,
    "url": "https://postman-echo.com/post"
}
```

Lo cual tiene bastante buena pinta pues podemos ver cómo entre las cabeceras está la que añadimos (`content-type`) y la `authorization` que contiene en base64 la concatenación `user:pass`. En `data` vemos qué ha recibido en el cuerpo del POST, y es el XML en cuestión.

Comment: Muchas gracias @abulafia.. he conseguido hacer que funcione gracias a poner el XML en un fuchero en vez de escribiéndolo en la consola a pelo. Es el único cambio que he hecho pero sin embargo, si me permite hacerlo con una petición GET. Es porque la API que uso recibe el XML en la petición y está configurada para recibirlo en el cuerpo. Nuevamente, muchas gracias!!!!